# .Net Core 7 C# AWS Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel scan with OR conditions

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-dynamodb

How do I scan with `ScanFilter` of multiple `OR` conditions?

```
ScanFilter prodFilter = new ScanFilter();
prodFilter.AddCondition("property1", ScanOperator.IsNotNull); // property1 not null
prodFilter.AddCondition("property2", ScanOperator.IsNotNull); // OR property2 not null
Search search = prodTable.Scan(prodFilter);
```

Comment: Hmm... I haven't worked with this technology, but is the 'legacy' [ConditionalOperator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LegacyConditionalParameters.ConditionalOperator.html) not applicable for v2?

Comment: actually... I think perhaps you should be using [ScanRequest FilterExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Scan.html); here's info more specific to SDK v3 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/DynamoDBv2/MDynamoDBScanScanRequest.html (which references to using FilterExpression)

Comment: Not clear to me how are the multiple conditions used - `AND` or `OR`?

Answer (score 0):

Source example:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/.dotnet/example_code/DynamoDB/LowLevelScan.cs#L69

FilterExpression can be extended like this:

```
var request = new ScanRequest
{
    TableName = "ProductCatalog",
    Limit = 2,
    ExclusiveStartKey = lastKeyEvaluated,
    ExpressionAttributeValues = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue> {
    {":val", new AttributeValue {
         N = "0"
     }},
    {":prop2", new AttributeValue {
         N = "1"
     }}
    },
    FilterExpression = "Price < :val and/or Property2 <> :prop2",

    ProjectionExpression = "Id, Title, Price"
};
```

I didn't test it but the concept should work.

Also, to **consider**:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-query-scan.html

According to this article, scanning is almost never good (performance, and apparently cost). You should reconsider how you design your database in favor of using queries.